# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp' in aurelia

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

I'm new to aurelia. When I started install aurelia-CLI its worked fine.Then I go through their [tutorial](http://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager). and then I try to run `au run` in cmd. Then I got error.

> { Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Promise (D:\JavaScript Project\News_V1\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\commands\gulp.js:19:20)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at module.exports.execute (D:\JavaScript Project\News_V1\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\commands\gulp.js:18:12)
>       at _establishProject.then.then (D:\JavaScript Project\News_V1\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\cli.js:36:24)
>       at  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

and also I tried this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188624/aurelia-cli-typescript-cannot-find-module-errors) already in stackoverflow but doesn't work for me.I did not see any file call `aurelia_json` in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`aurelia-cli` has a dependency on gulp which is not installed by default (it's a peer dependency). The recommended way to add `aurelia-cli` to your project is via `npm link`. Instructions for setting that up are on the [github page](https://github.com/aurelia/cli).

In a directory where you want aurelia-cli globally installed:

- `git clone https://github.com/aurelia/cli aurelia-cli`
- `cd aurelia-cli`
- `npm install`
- `npm link`
- `npm install gulp@^4.0.0 typescript babel-register babel-polyfill`

Now in your project directory:

- `npm link aurelia-cli`

And everything should work.

Comment: I tried these steps but I got error at last step. _PS D:\JavaScript Project\News_V1> npm link aurelia-cli
npm ERR! Link target resolves to the same directory as link source: D:\JavaScript Project\News_V1\node_modules\aurelia-cli_

Comment: That's strange. Could you remove the `aurelia-cli` directory from your `node_modules` directory in the project folder and try again? Regardless though, this should "just work". Mind sharing your `package.json`? Also it *may* be related to there being a space in the path to your project. I'd generally recommend avoiding any spaces in paths when working with npm et al. It's known to cause various hard to track down issues.

Comment: Hmm why are you supposed to clone and npm link unless you're actually gonna work on CLI itself? Just npm install it globally and it works fine. Have you tried just npm install again @Lakmi

Comment: Don't pin me on this but I recall it has something to do with a version conflict in gulp. Aurelia-cli needs v4 to work properly, but v4 is not an official release yet and so it could screw up other tooling and dependencies. By linking it first and *then* installing gulp (and the other deps), it will make for a less quirky environment

Comment: @FredKleuver I try but I got error when I type "npm link" I got this error "PS C:***\aurelia-cli> npm link
npm ERR! Link target resolves to the same directory as link source: C:*****\aurelia-cli

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\*****\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-21T09_41_18_413Z-debug.log
PS C:\*******\aurelia-cli>"

Comment: @Lakmi According to Google you're actually the first one who has this error. I'd take a wild guess: you installed aurelia-cli globally before and now you're trying to link it. You really need to make sure aurelia-cli is neither linked nor globally installed, then cleanly follow the instructions on aurelia-cli github page. So not just `npm uninstall -g aurelia-cli`, but also actually go to `%APPDATA%/npm/node_modules` and make sure `aurelia-cli` folder is **not** there before you try the linking procedure. It has to be clean.